# Python - join/understand .txt in .nc

Tags: coordinates, polygon, netcdf, txt, ocean

I need to plot together the salinity in background and ocean coordinates as a polygon (identifying the basin). **Find a manner the .nc recognize my .txt, and separete only the basin identificate**.

For example, I have salinity (.nc) all the oceans and the coordinates of Indian Ocean (.txt). So, I need identify only the coordinates the Indian Ocean at the .nc and separate this basin/data to my future analysis
I have two files:

***salinity.nc (georeferenced salinity data in Latxlon)***

#salinity (.nc)

```
salinity = xr.open_dataset('...salinity.nc')
salinity

salinity.coords['lon'] = ((salinity.coords['lon'] + 180) % 360) - 180
salinity = salinity.sortby(salinity.lon)

lon = salinity['lon']
lat = salinity['lat']

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

#plot

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=crs.PlateCarree())

im = ax.contourf(lon, lat, salinity, cmap="Spectral_r", extend="both")
```

[image]

***ocean.txt (a list with 666 rows x 2 columns, in each row a latxlon point)***

#indianocean (.txt)

```
indian = pd.read_csv('.....indianocean.txt', sep=';')
indian

#plot

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12)) 

m = Basemap()

m.plot(indian.lon, indian.lat, marker=None,color='blue')
```

[image]

***Updating...***

I'm using a shapefile to test, could plot the shape in a map, but I need to extract the salinity data only from my shapefile coordinates.

```
salinity = xr.open_dataset('...salinity.nc')

indshp = gpd.read_file('....indcoord.shp')
```

**#plot**

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_geometries(indshp.geometry, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', lw =2)


im = ax.contourf(lon, lat, salinity, cmap="Spectral_r", extend="both")
```

[image]

**Now, how I could use the salinity data only of the shapefile?**

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please revise the question to make the problem reproducible and more easily understood. Please ask a specific question instead of listing a bunch of things you’ve tried.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: It would help if you told us how you are plotting the data. It's impossible to know how to add a polygon to a map without knowing how it was generated

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit your question, but unfortunately the edit was not at all sufficient to clarify the issue. Please read this guide to creating a [mre], and maybe this one too: [crafting a minimal bug report](//matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports). For example, .txt files can be structured infinitely different ways. How are we to know how to help you parse yours without more information?

Comment: I hope the second edition helps.

Comment: thanks! please don't edit "edit" into your question though. we can all see the [edit log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74393841/revisions). the idea here is to provide a single, clear, consise question which others coming along would also find useful. that's also really helpful for us too - we're looking at a ton of questions every day, and picking through the history of your question to understand your intent is a lot harder than if you just present a single, clear problem setup. thanks :)

Comment: looking through your edits... It would still be really helpful to see what your data looks like. can you copy the results of `print(salinity)` and  `print(indian)` as a code block into your question?

Comment: Michael I organized all my question, for better understanding.